# cant save all the locations values into my array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am requesting to twitter to get all the locations of my users but then when i try to put them into my array all my objects get the same location(the last location of $.each).

its like i cant to loop through all the array values because of the each.function.i also tried putting outside the each.loop but same thing happens. Can someone tell me how to solve this.thanks!

```
    function lookup_locations(user_ids){
        $.getJSON("http://api.twitter.com/1/users/lookup.json?user_id="+user_ids+"&callback=?",
      function(data){

   $.each(data, function(i, item){
       var location=item.location; console.log(location);
       for(var i = 0; i < array.length;i++) {
      array[i].location = location;
                            }
            });

    console.log(array);
    });//get.json

    }//lookup function
```

Comment: You should rename that i variable in the for loop not to be mixed with the .each function

Comment: You're referring to a variable `array` -- `array.length ... array[i].location` -- that I don't see being declared or set anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the **for** loop; **i** is being incremented by the **$.each** so you don't need it.

```
var array = [];
$.each(data, function(i, item) {
    var location = item.location;
    array[i].location = location;
});
```